# javascript regexp to match path depth

Tags: javascript, regex

Been struggling for the last hour to try and get this regexp to work but cannot seem to crack it.

It must be a regexp and I cannot use split etc as it is part of a bigger regexp that searches for numerous other strings using .test().

```
(public\/css.*[!\/]?)

public/css/somefile.css
public/css/somepath/somefile.css
public/css/somepath/anotherpath/somefile.css
```

Here I am trying to look for path starting with public/css followed by any character except for another forward slash.

so "public/css/somefile.css" should match but the other 2 should not.

A better solution may be to somehow specify the number of levels to match after the prefix using something like

```
(public\/css\/{1,2}.*)
```

but I can't seem to figure that out either, some help with this would be appreciated.

### edit

No idea why this question has been marked down twice, I have clearly stated the requirement with sample code and test cases and also attempted to solve the issue, why is it being marked down ?

Comment: Using regex and split aren't really detrimental to one another.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `regex`:

```
/^(public\/css\/[^\/]*?)$/gm
```

1. `^` : Starts with
2. `[^/]` : Not `/`
3. `*?`: Any Characters
4. `$`: Ends with
5. `g`: Global Flag
6. `m`: Multi-line Flag

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
/public\/css\/[^\/]+$/
```

This will match 
public/css/[Any characters except for /]$

$ is matching the end of the string in regex.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I just tried that on regex101 does not appear to work ( https://regex101.com/r/oI6nJ9/2 )

Comment: Yes it does... The site you use  doesn't treat $ as line ending but end of file...